# Find the position of a related string in a list

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In my worksheet, B2:F2 and B8:D8 are already filled in.

I would like to find the formulas for B9:D9. For instance, B9 is `2` because we can find `Lee` in `Lee XXXX` and `Lee` is at the second place of B2:F2. C9 is 4 because we can find `Jim` in `Jim XXXX` and `Jim` is at the second place of B2:F2.

To check the relation of `Lee` and `Lee XXXX` (`Jim` and `Jim XXXX`), we could use SEARCH, left_substring (if such a function exists).

Both single formulas or array formula will be fine. Using LAMBDA function is secondary choice, because it is still in preview.

Could anyone help?

[image]

Comment: Can you share your approach / what you have tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what is needed is always the first "word":

```
=MATCH(LEFT(B8,FIND(" ",B8)-1),$B$2:$F$2,0)
```

[image]

If you want to search on any position in the string:

```
=AGGREGATE(15,7,(COLUMN($B$2:$F$2)-MIN(COLUMN($B$2:$F$2))+1)/(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(" "&$B$2:$F$2&" "," "&B8&" "))),1)
```

[image]

With FILTER instead of AGGREGATE:

```
=@FILTER((COLUMN($B$2:$F$2)-MIN(COLUMN($B$2:$F$2))+1),ISNUMBER(SEARCH(" "&$B$2:$F$2&" "," "&B8&" ")),"")
```